# Expand a shortened URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JavaScript which expands URLS (bit.ly, tiny.url, t.co, etc).
There is no such command called CURL in JS.

Since the code I am writing is for browser, XMLHttp Request is not allowing same origin access.

How to go about fixing this?

Comment: You may use XMLHTTPRequest, but when executing it in a browser, you'll get problems with the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Will XMLHTTPRequest make the script slow, since I have an array of about 500URL's which keeps updating and changing?

Comment: Quick Google Search gave this: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/3Ntnr/ Check this out

Comment: Are these 500 urls on the client page? In bulk?

Comment: Tried CURL in JS as posted in "What is the best way in PHP or JS to expand shortened URLs like Bitly, Tinyurl to find the original URL?"

Didn't work.

Comment: Yes. These URLs are on Client Page.

Comment: You are way better off using server-side code for this. For one thing, you can avoid CORS, and you don't have to worry about cross-browser problems. Plus, you can schedule this task to run whenever you like without degrading the user experience on the client side (think cron jobs).

Comment: Mods, this is NOT a duplicate of the linked question, as there is not a Javascript-related answer in the linked question. The other OP asked for a solution in either language and got ONLY php (server-side) answers. Take the flag off this question.